# How to smooth cocos2d-JS wheel spinning

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I want to make a wheel spinning like this, but it not smooth when rotating. How can I make it run smoothly?
[Demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wAUv6bQmeMYm50bVZxRVNYd28/view?usp=sharing)

```
        var audioengine = cc.audioEngine;
        audioengine.playMusic(res.Wheel_mp3, false);

        var spinNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*360) + 0);
        var angle = spinNumber + 13*360;   
        var action = new cc.RotateBy(18, angle);

        var ease = new cc.EaseSineOut(action);

        this.sprite.runAction(ease);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always create a new class extends Sprite and rewrite draw() or update() to do the job.

Here is the example:

```
var Wheel = Sprite.extend({
  ctor and other function : ...
  draw : function(){
    this._super();

    var speed = this. calculate Speed();
    var rotation = this.getRotation();
    var neoRotation = (rotation+speed)%360;
    this.setRotation(neoRotation)
  },

  caculateSpeed : function(){
    // some function that calculate the speed to simulate acceleration and deceleration.
    // return 0 means not rotate.
     return speed.
  } 
})
```

In order to calculate the speed, you may save some parameter(like current speed, current acceleration speed) to record the status.